# VBA Versions of VLookup

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

Apologies if I have missed this in an existing question.

Basically what I am wanting to achieve is:

- Return the last two Pass/Fail values for the relevant area
- If I use Area1 as an example I would return: "FAILFAIL"

[image: Example of the table I am populating]

Table is as above:

- **COLA =** A counter to count occurrences of area (currently formula)
- **COLB =** Actual area name (added with VBA)
- **COLC =** Audit Level (added with VBA)
- **COLD =** Blank
- **COLE =** Date (added with VBA)
- **COLF =** Pass/Fail  (added with VBA)
- **COLG =** Decision to promote or not based on evaluation of last two pass/fail values.
- **COLH =** Gives new Lvl dependent on G

I am currently using a hefty formula, but I would like to automate.

So ultimately I am looking to automate Column G & H.

I know if I can get the two results, I can just use an IF like below. But getting the results is evading me.

```
res1 = [RESULT1]
res2 = [RESULT2]

        
If res1 & res2 = "PASSPASS" Then
        Action = "Promote"
  ElseIf res1 & res2 = "FAILFAIL" Then
        Action = "Demote"
  Else
        Action = "Retest"
End If
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your current formula, please add a screenshot which also contains column and row headers. also specify in which cell your formula is entered and whether it works as intended. Also current content of "pass or fail" column doesn't seem to follow the rule you described, please post consistent example

Comment: Is it just a typo that the string parts starting with `Area`  in the last two rows of column A aren't followed by a *space*, i.e. `Area1 - .." instead of `Area 1 - 1` like in the first row? @WilliamJarvis

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) to hold the last value of Pass/Fail for comparison.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub process()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim PassFail As String, Action As String, n As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' sheet to process
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(r, "B")) ' area name
        PassFail = UCase(Trim(ws.Cells(r, "F")))
    
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            ' second or more occurance of area name
            If dict(key) = PassFail Then
                 ' same at last time
                If dict(key) = "PASS" Then
                    Action = "Promote"
                Else
                    Action = "Demote"
                End If
            Else
                ' different to last time
                Action = "Retest"
            End If

            ' update col G
            ws.Cells(r, "G") = Action

            ' store pass/fail for next occurance
            dict(key) = PassFail

        Else
            ' first occurance of area name
            dict.Add key, PassFail
            Action = ws.Cells(r, "G")
        End If

        ' update col H
        Select Case Action
            Case "Promote": n = 1
            Case "Demote": n = -1
            Case Else : n = 0
        End Select
        ws.Cells(r, "H") = ws.Cells(r, "C") + n '

    Next
    MsgBox iLastRow - 1 & " rows processed", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, after a bit of fettling I ended up with this, maybe a bit muddly, but it works exactly as I need it to.

```
    LastArea = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B:B"), AuditForm.Area1.Value)

last1 = AuditForm.Area1.Value & "-" & LastArea
last2 = AuditForm.Area1.Value & "-" & LastArea - 1
results = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(last1, Sheet2.Range("A2:F2000"), 5, False) & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(last2, Sheet2.Range("A2:F1000"), 5, False)
lev1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(last1, Sheet2.Range("A2:F1000"), 3, False)
lev2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(last2, Sheet2.Range("A2:F1000"), 3, False)

If lev1 = lev2 And results = "PASSPASS" Then
        action1 = "Promote"
    ElseIf lev1 = lev2 And results = "FAILFAIL" Then
        action1 = "Demote"
    Else
        action1 = "Retest"
End If

If action1 = "Promote" Then
       lvl = lvl + 1
  ElseIf action1 = "Demote" Then
       lvl = lvl - 1
  ElseIf action1 = "Retest" Then
       lvl = lvl
End If
```